# Add application to page

Tags: addition, facebook-page, facebook-timeline

I have a problem when I am trying to add my application to one of my pages. Earlier there has been an option in the left sidebar which simply says view profile application and then you could choose "Add to my page". Now that option is gone and instead there is just an option that says "view application timeline" or something like that. I cannot find how to add my applications to my different pages.

Anyone who have any idea how to solve this problem?

(I'm from Sweden, which explains my bad english)

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

The short version:
Enter this URL into your browser. Remember to replace YOUR_APP_ID first. There's currently no way to add an application just by clicking a link like before... :/

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed to work. But where on the page does the link show up? (I'm super new to Facebook so not familiar with how anything works).

Comment: It should show up among the other apps. Default ones are "Photos" and "Likes", I think. If the added application isn't visible, try clicking the arrow (located below the cogwheel).

Comment: I'd forgotten to give my app a "Tab name" or something like that. That's why it didn't show up. No error given though so took a while to figure it out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Please see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ 
This explains the recent changes to how Apps are associated with Pages and shows both how to create a community page and link it to an app, and how to use the new 'add to page' dialog

You can also add apps to a page via the API, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

try my "fix" @ http://admine.eu/addapp.html

here is part of the source and actually all you need:

```
window.open(
  "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=" +
  document.getElementById("appid").value +
  "&next=" +
  document.getElementById("appurl").value,

  "PageTab","width=1000,height=300"
)
```

`+document.getElementById("appid")` is the id of your app
`+document.getElementById("appurl")` is the canvas or tab URL of your app